# Wierd error with Mockito. when(repository.findById(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(user)) return null

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I have a controller's method:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return customerRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(CustomerNotFoundException::new);
    }
```

I have a test class and a method:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class CustomerControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private CustomerController controller;

    @Mock
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private Customer customer;
    private List<Customer> customerList;
....
@Test
    void getCustomer() {
        Customer customer1 = CustomerProviderUtils.generateEntity();
        when(customerRepository.findById(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(customer1));
        Customer responseCustomer = controller.getCustomer(1L);

        assertNotNull(responseCustomer);
}
```

When I run the test I got a CustomerNotFoundException.

What is wrong with this world or with my hands?) It should works, it works in other project with the same stack. Uhh...

I found that there is not one problem. The stacktrace below:

```
    com.jundevinc.internationalpizza.exception.CustomerNotFoundException
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at com.jundevinc.internationalpizza.api.controller.CustomerController.getCustomer(CustomerController.java:42)
    at com.jundevinc.internationalpizza.api.controller.CustomerController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6f790393.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685)
    at com.jundevinc.internationalpizza.api.controller.CustomerController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48cee886.getCustomer(<generated>)
    at com.jundevinc.internationalpizza.api.controller.CustomerControllerTest.getCustomer(CustomerControllerTest.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    .......
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at com.jundevinc.internationalpizza.api.controller.CustomerControllerTest.getCustomer(CustomerControllerTest.java:66)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.
```

Comment: You're mixing Mockito annotations (InjectMocks, Mock), used for unit tests, with Spring annotations (Autowired,  SpringBootTest), used for integration tests. The controller is created by Spring, and will not have the mock repository injected in it. Choose if you want a unit test, without any Spring support, and where you or the Mockito annotations create everything, or an integration test (with Autowired and MockBean), where Spring creates everything.

Comment: JB Nizet, thank you so much!) I delete Autowired and everything works well now)

Comment: You should also remove SpringBootTest

Comment: JB Nizet, oh my god, it is not load all context now that save a lot of time! Thank you so much!)